# Application class and object state

Tags: android

I've been making a research about the Application class and the ways to keep objects state, I've read a lot of stuff all over the web, include the android documentation (lifecycle, recommendations, etc), many questions/answers about the subject, and other stuff and still have some doubts and i want to to have this part very clear to future development. I guess that this is a common problem for every android developer so i want to know what experience (and not just documentation) said about it. So i have some questions:

1- The Application class can be kill from memory or initialized being the app in foreground?? Just the case that i have a subclass of Application with some static variables that keep state, i know that if the app go to background it can be killed for memory and then restarted but can it happen when it is in foreground??

2- If the app memory can be erased or initialized in any moment by the OS the only reliable way to keep state of objects in by a database or files?? (Really hope NOT!!)

3- Any other tips that can help about this issue.

Comment: also, you phone battery can be removed without notification at any time. commit your data to sharedpref, file, database or whatever early to be sure you keep them.

Comment: i don't want to keep my data, there is data that only make sense in the memory in the lifecycle of the app and i don't want to save it never

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of my experience you're overacting and over-thinking on what the documentation says. Most application do not need and should not extend Application.

1- The application will be killed whilst in foreground only in the most extreme circumstances. So you should forget this part for now and just worry about your app itself. If it happens the user will re-start your app from the beginning.

2- state objects you should keep on the activity life cycle (NOT APPLICATION) by overriding onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() and reading their values back on onCreate(Bundle savedInstances) and getLastNonConfigurationInstance(). Those methods are for activities might be deprecated, I know some are, read the documentation and they'll tell your which are the substitutes on fragments. USE FRAGMENTS. Also state can be passed from activity to other through the intents/bundles.

3- to keep persistent data you should use database and SharedPreferences, activity state use the available activity and fragment call backs. If somehow, your application have some fairly particular needs you can create a singleton, but believe me when I say, 99% of application don't need.

hope it helped!

Comment: yes, maybe I'm overacting but it's because I've seen some strange behavior in my last app, i have some static variables in Application subclass and it works fine, but once in a while the vars just seems to initialize just like that and that's why I begin to search and wonder how it works, anyway yours is a really good answer and you're right about avoid that kind of model, noted for future development